# iOS 8 swift Soap web service communication

Tags: web-services, soap, swift, ios8

I need communication with my Asp.net SOAP web service with using Swift . Is there any open source library written or could anyone give me a starting point to do it myself?

NOTE : I am not familiar with Objective-C but I have experience in connection between Android and .Net using SOAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this new simple and lightweight XML parser for iOS in Swift - [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML)

You can use it to read XML data like this:

```
let someValue = xmlDocument["element"]["child"]["anotherChild"].value
```

or you can use it to build XML string like this:

```
let document = AEXMLDocument()
let element = document.addChild("element")
element.addChild("child")
document.xmlString // returns XML string of the entire document structure
```

You can use this to generate SOAP requests and parse responses.

Answer (score 0):

Starting points are

- `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession` for downloading the SOAP response,
- `NSXMLParser` for parsing it.

No need for external frameworks :-).

Comment: Not for Downloading only . I also need posting parameters like logins

Comment: I don't like that library either. Not very clean.